# n-dimensional sliding window with Pandas or Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, r, numpy, pandas

How do I do the R(xts) equivalent of rollapply(...., by.column=FALSE), using Numpy or Pandas? When given a dataframe, pandas rolling_apply seems only to work column by column instead of providing the option to provide a full (window-size) x (data-frame-width) matrix to the target function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

xx = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros([10, 10]))
pd.rolling_apply(xx, 5, lambda x: np.shape(x)[0]) 

    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5
5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5
6   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5
7   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5
8   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5
9   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5
```

So what's happening is rolling_apply is going down each column in turn and applying a sliding  5-length window down each one of these, whereas what I want is for the sliding windows to be a 5x10 array each time, and in this case, I would get a single column vector (not 2d array) result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I indeed cannot find a way to compute "wide" rolling application in pandas
docs, so I'd use numpy to get a "windowing" view on the array and apply a ufunc
to it.  Here's an example:

```
In [40]: arr = np.arange(50).reshape(10, 5); arr
Out[40]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
       [35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
       [45, 46, 47, 48, 49]])

In [41]: win_size = 5

In [42]: isize = arr.itemsize; isize
Out[42]: 8
```

`arr.itemsize` is 8 because default dtype is `np.int64`, you need it for the following "window" view idiom:

```
In [43]: windowed = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(arr,
                                                    shape=(arr.shape[0] - win_size + 1, win_size, arr.shape[1]),
                                                    strides=(arr.shape[1] * isize, arr.shape[1] * isize, isize)); windowed
Out[43]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]],

       [[ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
        [25, 26, 27, 28, 29]],

       [[10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
        [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34]],

       [[15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
        [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
        [35, 36, 37, 38, 39]],

       [[20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
        [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
        [35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
        [40, 41, 42, 43, 44]],

       [[25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
        [35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
        [40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
        [45, 46, 47, 48, 49]]])
```

Strides are number of bytes between two neighbour elements along given axis,
thus `strides=(arr.shape[1] * isize, arr.shape[1] * isize, isize)` means skip 5
elements when going from windowed[0] to windowed[1] and skip 5 elements when
going from windowed[0, 0] to windowed[0, 1].  Now you can call any ufunc on the
resulting array, e.g.:

```
In [44]: windowed.sum(axis=(1,2))
Out[44]: array([300, 425, 550, 675, 800, 925])
```

Comment: Yep - though really when I see this it reminds me that if I'm going to have to count bytes then why not go the whole way and do C or Fortran. This is a great little intro to the strides though so I thank you, immerr. Sometimes going lower level is so refreshingly rewarding.

Comment: Well, if you go C or Fortran you miss the convenience in writing 80% of the code whose performance doesn't really matter. It does feel "hacky" though and probably that's why it's well hidden under "stride_tricks" name. In some cases you can use `scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter` and `generic_filter1d`, but they never worked for me: `generic_filter` iterates over columns and `generic_filter1d` goes row-by-row but disallows specifying 2d windows.

Comment: So does the as_strided make a new array containing all the windows? Or is it a view on the original array/some kind of generator? Because if it is making a new array of arrays this could be very memory intensive no? I am working with data structures that can have hundreds of thousands of rows, then iterating my windows size down each row sequentially. I guess I'll have to test it out. Otherwise this looks great because it will also allow n-dimensional cases and even window shapes that are not the full length of one of the dimensions.

Comment: If I try this `whos` in ipython informs me that arr is approximately 5 times smaller (38MB) than `windowed` (190MB), suggesting that it's not a view, but a copy. However, if I set a value in in the original array or in the window, it also changes in the other, suggesting it's a view. Is this some numpy-magic? Or is ipython just wrong?

Comment: @Herbert, you should be able to check if the array is a copy or a view by comparing `{arr/windowed}.flags.owndata`. Another option is to compare `{arr/windowed}.__array_interface__['data']` and see if they point to the same memory. It could be that ipython is wrong here, but i haven't touched numpy in a while, so things might have changed.