# Unlike Numpy, Pandas doesn't seem to like memory strides

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Pandas seems to be missing a R-style matrix-level rolling window function (`rollapply(..., by.column = FALSE)`), providing only the vector based version. Thus I tried to follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26371509/n-dimensional-sliding-window-with-pandas-or-numpy) and it works beautifully with the example which can be replicated, but it doesn't work with pandas `DataFrame`s even when using the (seemingly identical) underlying Numpy array.

Artificial problem replication:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

test = [[x * y for x in range(1, 10)] for y in [10**z for z in range(5)]]
mm = np.array(test, dtype = np.int64)
pp = pd.DataFrame(test).values
```

`mm` and `pp` look identical:

[image]

The numpy directly-derived matrix gives me what I want perfectly:

```
as_strided(mm, (mm.shape[0] - 3 + 1, 3, mm.shape[1]), (mm.shape[1] * 8, mm.shape[1] * 8, 8))
```

That is, it gives me 3 strides of 3 rows each, in a 3d matrix, allowing me to perform computations on a submatrix moving down by one row at a time.

[image]

But the pandas-derived version (identical call with `mm` replaced by `pp`):

```
 as_strided(pp, (pp.shape[0] - 3 + 1, 3, pp.shape[1]), (pp.shape[1] * 8, pp.shape[1] * 8, 8))
```

[image]

is all weird like it's transposed somehow. Is this to do with column/row major order stuff?

I need to do matrix sliding windows in Pandas, and this seems my best shot, especially because it is really fast. What's going on here? How do I get the underlying Pandas array to behave like Numpy?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that the `.values` returns the underlying data in Fortran order (as you speculated):

```
>>> mm.flags # NumPy array
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  ...

>>> pp.flags # array from DataFrame
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  ...
```

This confuses `as_strided` which expects the data to be arranged in C order in memory.

To fix things, you could copy the data in C order and use the same strides as in your question:

```
pp = pp.copy('C')
```

Alternatively, if you want to avoid copying large amounts of data, adjust the strides to acknowledge the column-order layout of the data:

```
as_strided(pp, (pp.shape[0] - 3 + 1, 3, pp.shape[1]), (8, 8, pp.shape[0]*8))
```

Answer (score 4):

> Is this to do with column/row major order stuff?

Yes, see `mm.strides` and `pp.strides`.

> How do I get the underlying Pandas array to behave like Numpy?

The Numpy array `mm` is "C-contiguous" and that's why the stride trick works. If you want to call the exact same code on the array underlying the DataFrame, you can use `np.ascontiguousarray` first. Or maybe it would be better to write the data windowing while taking the array `strides` and `itemsize` into account.